# Несколько вопросов по программированию файлообменника

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Программирую [файлообменник](http://putit.ru), чтобы восстановить пробелы в знаниях и узнать много нового.

Господа, опять много вопросов:

1. Как заставить пользователя не посмотреть, а скачать картинку, текст, при клике на ссылку? Как это делается в гуглопочте, к примеру.
2. Так и не нашел способа проверить размер файла до загрузки на сервер, выбранный через хтмл файловый инпут (форму). Способ, признанный решением в прошлом моем вопросе, оказывается, работает далеко не во всех браузерах.
3. Как добавить значение переменной в буфер обмена на javascript, jquery? Возможно ли это?
4. Можно ли как-то реализовать шкалу процесса загрузки файла на сервер через javascript, jquery? Или только флэш и схожие технологии, типа сильверлайт?

Хочется от Вас не готового кода, а мануалов, решений и предложений, что гуглить, читать.
Благодарю.

Comment: Стало интерестно, найдутся ли тут дурачки тебе отвечать?....

Comment: отвечу на первый вопрос только :)

посылай заголовок соответствующий через header()

Comment: > Способ, признанный решением в прошлом моем вопросе, оказывается, работает далеко не во всех браузерах.

Только в IE ниже 10 версии не работает. Но согласитесь, это намного лучше, чем вообще без проверки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@Gorets](/users/3608/gorets), а в чем дело?!

1)

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename"');
```

2)

Никак. Универсальных способов нет, а те, которые могут помочь легко обмануть.
Ограничения все кладете на сервер, соответственно держите лишние 10-20 максимальных объемов, которые можно успеть залить за время взаимодействия с сервером.
Пример: максимальное время запроса - минута, максимальная скорость на вход - 100мбит/с.
Итог: у вас должно быть свободно ~8-15 гиг.

3)

Кукисы. С буфером обмена, к счастью, JS работать не умеет (ActiveX не в счет).

4)

Универсальных способов нет. Некоторые браузеры это умеют, типа лисы, но не все.

Comment: > держите лишние 10-20 максимальных объемов, которые можно успеть залить за время взаимодействия с сервером

Зачем? [`client_max_body_size`](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size) - при попытке отправить файл больше этого значения, nginx просто разорвет соединение. При всем желании никаких гигабайтов закачать не удастся.

Comment: Угу. Но заметьте, что
1) Клиентов много.(Для этого и делается запас. Чтобы при всем желании одновременно закачивающие клиенты не забили диск).
2) nginx - тоже со стороны сервера
3) ...он не у всех настроен

Comment: 3) делается как-то костылями через флэш. Но вообще где-то я точно видел добавление в буфер, кроссбраузерное, хотя и на костылях

Answer (score 2):

Нажал сразу на "отправить на сервер" и ничего не выбирал

> Файлы данного вида запрещены к
> загрузке на сервер, сожмите его в .rar
> или в .zip архив.

И дальше закрыл страницу.

Comment: Переименовал exe в zip. Загрузилось. **Trollface**

Comment: Да не exe итак хорошо туда грузятся.
а вот то что php я переименовал в zip и теперь ползаю по серверу это круто! Дыры зашивай в своём файлообменнике.

Comment: php я переименовал в zip// Я не хотел этого писать, чтобы не компрометировать. >.<

Comment: Ну что уж теперь делать! ^_^ 

Нужно изначально проверять все, а не показывать тем, кто иногда "страдает переименованием файлов" и находит интересные дыры.

Comment: @Shrek, а объясните человеку темному (мне)

>а вот то что php я переименовал в zip и теперь ползаю по серверу

Как это может происходить ? Он что, как-то позволяет обращаться напрямую (GET, POST) к залитым файлам ?

Или я совсем ерунду сказал и дело в чем-то другом ?

Comment: @Shrek, так как насчет объяснить , или умалчиваете по принципиальным соображениям (нераспространение потенциально опасных знаний) ?

Comment: @avp слушай, ты же знаешь как работает php, как можно залив один файл, с его помощью залить целый shell, с помощью которого можно не просто ползать по серверу, а еще и обращаться к БД править файлы и прочее.

А про переименование php в zip тут то что объяснять? Это дыра, причем огромная.

Comment: @Shrek, т.о. я правильно понял, что ТС позволяет обращаться (видимо GET) к залитому файлу ?

Comment: @avp Ну если аккуратно то да :)? немного конечно подшаманить пришлось, но итог.

Comment: Тоже не понимаю, если php переименовать в zip, как можно ползать по серверу?

Answer (score 1):

Ну первую "проблему" можно решить гораздо гибче с помощью волшебного .htaccess:

```
 AddType application/octet-stream .rar .doc .mov .avi .pdf .xls .mp4
```

Как понятно, это список файлов, котрые будут предлагаться сохранять, а не открывать в браузере. Зато не придется каждый раз отправлять хедеры.

---

Четвертую можно решить на [HTML5 progress`ом.](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_progress.asp)

Comment: Супер.  
 
    <progress value="22" max="100"></progress>

Такую ляльку можно за пять минут из дивов собрать. Одна проблема:
Даже если мне удастся ежесекундными запросами на сервак узнать размер уже загруженного содержимого(value), я НЕ знаю max. Так что штука довольно бесполезная в свете вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

По поводу четвертого вопроса - http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php